# Transactional jobs in Pentaho Kettle CE

Tags: transactions, pentaho

I want to make my job transactional so I should proceed two different way:

1)-by making each job's transformations transactional(check chexbox"make the transformation database transactional") and it doesn't work, and here is my question: how to make my job transactional with taking in consideration that my transformations use table output step and insert/update step which get connection to database every try?

2)-by make my hole job transactional but i can't found the checkbox for a job?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by making it transactional

Comment: Which version of Pentaho are you running?  I believe they added such a checkbox in the latest version.

Comment: I am using the latest version community edition "pdi-ce-6.0.1.0-386.zip" from sourceforge.

Comment: i just downloaded the latest version 6.1 it doesn't respond to my need, i ask if there is a solution yet??

Answer (score 1):

I've been investigating the topic for my needs as well and it seems that this option is only available for Enterprise Edition starting from version 5.0.

By marking transformations as transactional each transformation is opening it's own separate transaction, so that will not work for you. I've experimented job executors and mapping transformations for that case to no avail.

As a workaround for small projects where there is no money or (not involving a huge amount of code of Pentaho db transactions rewritten) perform a database backup and restore on failure.

For smaller cases perform backups for only the tables involved in the process that are being modified.

Answer (score 0):

How about the solution: Create the parent transformation package to call child transformation packages, set the transaction for parent transformation package. And then, create the job to call the parent package.